# Saving a QImage to QBuffer

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qimage, qdatastream

I am doing something like this:

```
QImage image(width, height, QImage::Format_RGB32);
frame.fill(QColor(255, 255, 255).rgb());

QBuffer buffer;
buffer.open(QBuffer::ReadWrite);
QDataStream out(&buffer);
```

Option 1:

```
out << image;
```

Option 2:

```
out.writeRawData((char *) image.constBits(), image.byteCount()) ;
```

Option 1 is pretty slow and I am not sure if Option 2 is the correct way to do?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`QImage::save`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qimage.html#save-2) to write directly to a `QIODevice`, be it a buffer or a file.

```
image.save(buffer);
```

Option 2 looks pretty gross compared to Option 1; I would certainly prefer Option 1 aesthetically.  But I would prefer the API I mentioned over both the options you give.

You can read more about image read/write [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qimage.html#reading-and-writing-image-files).

Answer (score 1):

I have just done something similar

```
QByteArray byteArray;
QBuffer buffer(&byteArray);
image.save(&buffer, "PNG"); // writes the image in PNG format inside the buffer
```

To output the buffer I would use a QString, I used this for converting to base64

```
QString imgBase64 = QString::fromLatin1(byteArray.toBase64().data());
```